# How to remove abnormal space in Elastic (jquery plugin)

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, textarea

Here is the pic from Elastic...
First time load the page:
[image]

Focus, and blur:[image]

after typing ...[image]

I don't want the space occur, how can I remove them?? Thank you.

Example from Elastic:
http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Answer (score 1):

Delete linheight out of line 113 so that it becomes `var goalheight = $twin.height();`

Depending on how you want it to function, you might also want to remove lineheight from line 111 so that it becomes `if(Math.abs($twin.height() - $textarea.height()) > 3){`

Answer (score 0):

well when I changed the style to height: 40px; it shows without the empty line.. when I started to write, the line poped up and then when I clicked outside text area, the line disappeared.

I couldn't come out with better solution.